# PostgreSQL refuses connection

Tags: postgresql

My PostgreSQL 9.3 server running on windows 8.1 has started to refuse connections. It worked fine last time I used it two weeks ago, but first it had a fatal configuration file (strange because I had not edited it) - so I reset that to the default. Then it refused my connection.

The data/pg_log directory is empty.

Error message:

> could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is
>   the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP
>   connections on port 5432? could not connect to server: Connection
>   refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost"
>   (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

The server is running on localhost and should be accepting connections to port 5432 according to the postgresql.conf file.

Comment: If you just updated the conf file, restart the service

Comment: Thanks!  I swear I did it, but was wrong!